# Calling Email OnError from ScriptTask of SSIS

Tags: ssis, sendmail, onerror

I have a simple SSIS package with a single script task on it.  I have an OnError event with a Send Mail task.

All i'm doing is testing to see if i can send an email when i detect an error withing my script.
However the variable i use to hold the Error message for my email causes an error.

"A deadlock was detected while trying to lock variable "User::errMsg" for read access. "

Here is the very simple script

```
public void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                int x = 2;
                if (x ==2)
                {
                    throw new Exception("The number was  2");
                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Dts.Variables["errMsg"].Value = e.Message;
                Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "here", "my error", "", 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
```

How can i pass a message to my send email when an error occurs in my script task ?

Answer (score 1):

SSIS variables are `locked` and are relased only in its `Post Execute event` .In your case `errMsg` variable gets locked by the script task  and the same time the variable is accessed in `On Error event` by the `SendMail` component creating a `deadlock` situation .You need to specifically `unlock` the variable before it is accessed by other components during its execution phase.

Try this :-

```
 catch (Exception e)
        {
            Variables lockedVariables = null;
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("errMsg", ref lockedVariables);
            lockedVariables["errMsg"].Value = e.Message;
            lockedVariables.Unlock();


            Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "here", "my error", "", 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

        }
```

This will ensure that before the error occurs ,the variable is unlocked and can be accessed in execution events such as `On Error` or `OnExecStatusChanged`.

More on how to handle these type of deadlocks is explained by Todd McDermid in his [blog](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.in/2010/08/use-readonlyvariables-and.html)